# How to update phone number in DocuSign programmatically

Tags: python, django-views, docusignapi

I am working on a site using Docusign for signing contracts, the problem is if the user changed his phone number in his personal information in the site, the phone number does not change in Docusign when the user get sms verification it remains the old phone number:

The result should be if the user changed the phone number in his personal information and then he or she want to sign his contract his new phone number should be there in the sms verification (DoscuSign)

I wrote the following code but I am getting the following problem :'Person' object is not iterable.

I have a file called DocuSign service:

```
    def get_recipients(self, signers: List[Dict]) -> Recipients:
    recipients = []
    for signer in signers:
        recipient = Signer(
            email=signer["email"],
            name=signer["name"],
            recipient_id=signer["recipient_id"],
            client_user_id=signer["client_user_id"],
            routing_order=signer["routing_order"],
            id_check_configuration_name="SMS Auth $",
            sms_authentication={"senderProvidedNumbers": [signer["phone_number"]]},
        )
        sign_here = SignHere(
            anchor_string=f"Please Sign {signer['anchor_string']}",
            anchor_units="pixels",
            anchor_y_offset="10",
            anchor_x_offset="20",
            recipient_id=signer["recipient_id"],
        )
        place_signed = Text(
            anchor_string=f"PlaceSigned{signer['anchor_string']}",
            required=True,
            tab_label=f"PlaceSigned{signer['anchor_string']}",
        )
        date_signed = DateSigned(
            anchor_string=f"DateSigned{signer['anchor_string']}",
        )
        full_name = FullName(
            anchor_string=f"FullName{signer['anchor_string']}",
        )
        recipient.tabs = Tabs(
            sign_here_tabs=[sign_here],
            text_tabs=[place_signed],
            date_signed_tabs=[date_signed],
            full_name_tabs=[full_name],
        )
        recipients.append(recipient)
    return Recipients(signers=recipients)

def update_recipients(self, contract, signers: List[Dict]):
    """
    Update the information of the signers for the contract.
    """
    api_client = self._create_api_client()
    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
    recipients = self.get_recipients(signers=signers)
    return envelope_api.update_recipients(
        account_id=self._ACCOUNT_ID,
        envelope_id=str(contract.envelope_id),
        recipients=recipients,
    )
```

in the views of the contract I have this code:

```
@action(methods=["GET"], detail=True, url_path="sign", permission_classes=[IsEmployerOrLandlord])
def sign_contract(self, request, pk):
    contract = self.get_object()
    signing_person = request.user.person
    ds = DocuSignService()
    ds.update_recipients(contract=contract, signers=signing_person)

    if contract.envelope_id:
        status = ContractStatusUtil().get_and_set_employer_rental_contract_status(contract)

        if signing_person.employer_id:
            if status is ContractStatusChoices.TO_BE_SIGNED_SECOND_PARTY or status is ContractStatusChoices.SIGNED:
                return Response(data={'detail': 'Contract already signed.'}, status=httpstatus.HTTP_226_IM_USED)
        elif signing_person.lessor:
            if status is ContractStatusChoices.SIGNED:
                return Response(data={'detail': 'Contract already signed.'}, status=httpstatus.HTTP_226_IM_USED)
    else:
        envelope = ds.create_envelope(contract=contract, signing_person=signing_person)
        contract.envelope_id = envelope.envelope_id
        contract.signer = signing_person
        contract.save()

        logger.info("SigningContract - envelop " + str(envelope) + " created for signing_person" + str(signing_person))

    signer_index = 0 if request.user.person.employer_id else 1
    util = RecipientViewUtil()
    logger.info("SigningContract - returning response for docusign service for " + str(contract) +
                ", signing_person " + str(signing_person))
    return Response(
        data={"signing_url": util.get_signing_url(contract=contract, signer_index=signer_index,
                                                               signing_person=signing_person)},
        status=httpstatus.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Can someone help me please and check my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phone number for a specific recipient in a specific envelope is what you want to update? or a contact in the system that can be re-used for many recipients in many envelopes?

Comment: Can you clarify which this "site" is? Is this within DocuSign or your private site?
How do you handle this info from your app?

Answer (score 0):

This code is using the older method to obtain phone authentication and may not allow you to update the phone number as you need to have it in the code.
The newer method is like this ([in Python](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eSignature/examples/eg037_sms_delivery.py)):

```
    signerPhoneNumber = RecipientPhoneNumber(
        country_code=args["country_code"],
        number=args["phone_number"]
    )

    # Create the signer recipient model
    signer1 = Signer(
        name=args["signer_name"],
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        phone_number=signerPhoneNumber
    )
```

You can update the phone number by calling [this endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/) to modify the recipients of the envelope and send a new phone number.